# Jquery.highlight <a> onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, cfml

I have a table on a page that lists users.  The initial rendering is a "short list" that only has minimal data. Each row has a plus image and a minus image. The plus image is as follows;

```
<a href="" onClick='javascript: ColdFusion.navigate("#request.controlurl#calllist/CallListDetail.cfm?UsersID=#CallList.usersID#&callListID=#attributes.callListID#","Ind_#CallList.usersID#");checkKW(); return false;'><img class="plus" src="#request.controlURL#images/plus.gif" border="0"></a>
```

When the plus icon is clicked I display more detailed data.  I want to highlight certain keywords in that data.  In the test I'm working on I have 2 rows.  When I click on the first plus icon I get the detailed data but without highlighting.  When I click on the second row plus icon, the highlighting appears in the first row.

I'm using [Jquery highlight js at](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html). The checkKW function is;

```
function checkKW(){
        $(".commdiv").highlight(document.getElementById('keywordscheckdiv').innerHTML);
        alert('one');
    }
```

A sample of one of the divs I want to highlight words in is;

```
<div style="padding:2px 10px 5px 10px; " class="commdiv">
                    <strong>Date:</strong> #dateformat(qCallListComms.Date_Entered,"yyyy/mm/dd")# <strong>Cons:</strong> #qCallListComms.username#
                    <strong>Type:</strong> #qCallListComms.communication_type#&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;#qCallListComms.comment#
                </div>
```

Comment: why dont u include ColdFusion in tag?

Comment: It tends to make Jquery folks ignore the post.  I don't know why.

Comment: Check for javascript errors using your browser's debugging tools: Firebug, FF's web console, ... Also, timing might be a factor. You should invoke `checkKW` after the call succeeds ie In your [callbackHandler](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS0ef8c004658c1089-6262c847120f1a3b244-7fd0.html). That said, any reason you are using `ColdFusion.navigate` instead of jQuery? *RE: I don't know why* That is common with questions that are mix of languages. Someone familiar with language A, but not B, may not understand all of the pieces involved and does want to give the wrong advice.

Comment: The div hasn't been rendered when the checkKW function fires.  That's why highlighting works on the already-rendered divs.  Adding checkKW as the callback did the trick. Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From comments ...)

Check for javascript errors using your browser's debugging tools: Firebug, FF's web console, ... Also, timing might be a factor. You should invoke `checkKW` *after* the call succeeds and the div is rendered ie In your [callbackHandler](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS0ef8c004658c1089-6262c847120f1a3b244-7fd0.html).

That said, any reason you are using ColdFusion.navigate instead of jQuery?